# Why does Kotlin resolve return type inconsistently?

Tags: kotlin, types, return, return-type

Given the following code:

```
inline fun <reified T> T?.or(other: () -> T): T {
    return this ?: other()
}

fun getValue(): String {
    while (true) {
        return "Value 1"
    }
}

fun main() {
    val value: String? = null

    // get value from getValue() function if value is null
    val valueFromFunction = value.or(::getValue)
    println(valueFromFunction)

    // get value from anonymous function if value is null
    val anonymousFunction: () -> String = fun(): String {
        while (true) {
            return "Value 2"
        }
    }
    val valueFromAnonymous: String = value.or(anonymousFunction)
    println(valueFromAnonymous)

    // get value from lambda if value is null
    val lambda: () -> String = lambda@ {
        while (true) {
            return@lambda "Value 3"
        }
        return@lambda ""
    }
    val valueFromLambda: String = value.or(lambda)
    println(valueFromLambda)

    // get value from inline anonymous function if value is null
    val valueFromInlineAnonymous: String = value.or(fun(): String {
        while (true) {
            return "Value 4"
        }
        return ""
    })
    println(valueFromInlineAnonymous)

    // get value from inline lambda if value is null
    val valueFromInlineLambda: String = value.or {
        while (true) {
            return@or "Value 5"
        }
        return@or ""
    }
    println(valueFromInlineLambda)
}
```

Why is it needed for value 3, 4 and 5 to add the extra unreachable return statement after the while loop, whereas with value 1 and 2 I don't need to?

If I remove the unreachable return statement for inline anonymous functions and for lambdas, the code doesn't compile because it thinks that the return type is `Unit`, however when a function reference is used or if the anonymous function is saved to a variable, this extra return statement is not needed. Also, for a lambda that is saved to a variable, the extra unreachable return statement is still needed.

Is there any good reason for this inconsistency?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The lambda cases are instances of this rather old bug [KT-24191](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/KT-24191/Compiler-does-not-allow-return-from-unconditional-control-flow-in-lambdas), or [KT-25023](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/KT-25023/Infinite-loops-in-lambdas-containing-returnlabel-dont-coerce-to-any-type). I suspect the anonymous function literal case is also related. There are also many other similar issues about the typechecker not understanding `return`s inside infinite loops.

This [comment](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/KT-25023/Infinite-loops-in-lambdas-containing-returnlabel-dont-coerce-to-any-type#focus=Comments-27-3084519.0-0) explains what is probably going on:

> And the question is about such case:
>
> ```
> fun foo() {
>     val x = run<Int> {
>         while (true) {
>             return@run 1 // Error: Type mismatch: inferred type is Unit but Int was expected
>         }
>     }
> }
> ```
>
> How should we typecheck such constructs?  Problem: the type of while
> is `Unit` (because it's a statement), but it's used here as the last
> expression in lambda (for `run`) and should be of the type `Int`